# ES6 is not supported after Electron packaging

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, electron

I'm using various [ES6 syntax](http://es6-features.org) (such as `import` etc.) & [React](https://reactjs.org/) code ([JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)) in my [Electron](https://electronjs.org/)-based application. During the development, I'm using the [electron-prebuilt-compile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-prebuilt-compile) package (as a *dev-dependency*) in order to support these new features and it works perfectly fine without any errors.

But after packaging my app using the [electron-packager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-packager) package and running the distributable application file, I experiencing unsupported ES6-related errors such as:

```
Unexpected token import
```

That's is how I run the electron-packager command (notice to the platform & architecture flags):

```
electron-packager . MyCoolApp --platform=linux --arch=x64
```

Any reason why a packaged/distributable version of my application does not support ES6/React features?

Comment: I think this is beacause `electron-packager` downloads the current Electron binaries itself when `electron` is not explicitly set in your package.json (which I assume, since you're using `electron-prebuilt-compile`) or when you're not on the platform you want to package to.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner and if electron will be explicitly set in my package.json, it should work fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

it turns out that *devDependencies* are being omitted during packaging by default, which means that the `electron-prebuild-compile` package is "out of the game" for a packaged application and without it ES6 can't be transcompiled. So in order to deactivate this default behavior, I had to call the packager command with the `--no-prune` flag so that the *devDependencies* will remain without being deleted:

```
electron-packager . MyCoolApp --platform=linux --arch=x64 --no-prune
```

In addition, I had to introduce a new script (let's name it: `es6-init.js`) for initialization of the main app's script in order to "compile" the code before rendering (it should be used as the main entry point script of your application):

```
var appRoot = path.join(__dirname, '..');

require('electron-compile').init(appRoot, require.resolve('./main'));
```

References:

- https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-compile#how-does-it-work-slightly-harder-way
- https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager

Comment: FWIW, `devDependencies` is strictly there for those dependencies you need for dev but not production. It's not a good idea to remove this separation. Instead, I would suggest moving this one from `devDependencies` to `dependencies` to mark its true purpose in your build.

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs(and with it, Electron) does not support `import` and `export`. You will need to use `require();`

Comment: using the electron-prebuilt-compile package, you should be able running electron with ES6 features