# Why doesn't electron 2.0 support TypeScript (ES6) import?

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, electron

To clarify, my question is not rhetorical; I'm actually trying to understand technically ***why* the ES6 import statement does not work**.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964383/node-require-versus-es6-import-why-doesnt-this-example-work) appears to be duplicate, but the accepted answer will not TypeScript transpile for electron. For example:

```
import * as electron from 'electron';
```

results in

```
.\node_modules\.bin\tsc
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:8:20 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Event'.
8 type GlobalEvent = Event;
```

[This 2 year old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39400980/608220) states the reason is dependent components (nodejs and chrome) don't support it, which is no longer true, so probably not the technical reason. The related electron community discussion also suggests [the status is unresolved](https://discuss.atom.io/t/does-electron-support-es6/19366/19).

Workaround suggestions so that we can maintain our existing code style are also welcome, but not my primary question. Possible workarounds:

- [use babel or TypeScript transpiler options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39400980/608220)
- [switch to
  `electron-prebuilt-compile`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49581687/608220)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35964408/608220) has a related title, but the details ask an HTML-specific question, and so is not what I'm looking for.

Lastly, I should mention that I'm not certain electron does not support ES6 imports under some conditions; e.g. I may be missing something fundamental. My assumption is partly because the [electron 2.0 manual](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#using-electron-apis) shows `const requires()` destructuring syntax instead of imports.

Comment: I would suggest asking this on [Electron's GitHub site](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues). Asking it here would encourage speculation and rumor-mongering. See for example this issue: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12011

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you. I don't know why I didn't think of that. I suppose I was assuming it was related to a general ES6 or TypeScript thing I didn't understand, and I would be rebuffed for asking it in an electron forum without more information. Also, your electron issue link, though closed, is very helpful.